# Issue while recreating AWS authentication profile in Terraform

Tags: terraform, devops

Followed below mentioned step for creating the `sso` profile in *AWS* using command prompt and leverage it to create `S3 bucket`:

**Steps to Setup Profile:**

In *PowerShell* ran: `aws configure sso`

```
sso_start_url = url

sso_region = us-east-1
```

**Note:** It will take  to browser for login and verification. Once verified, it retrieves the  role, After that i have selected the role

1. CLI default client Region [eu-west-1]: `us-east-1`
2. CLI default output format [json]: `json`
3. CLI profile name : `<<Provide your choice of name>>`
4. This will create `.aws` folder and config file under your home directory (under `\User\\<<username>>`)

**Steps to use profile:**

1. Ran below command to set profile in PowerShell
   `setx AWS_PROFILE <<profile name>>`  and configure the access key and secret key using command aws configure
2. After setting profile in current PowerShell session,  trying to create the `S3` bucket, but unable to create it.
3. Got error like

   > No valid credentials for AWS provider

**Profile recreation steps:**

1. To recreate profile  I  have deleted the .aws folder  which was created in the  home directory path (under `\User\\<<username>>\\.aws`)
2. Now, while trying to create new profile using aws configure `sso` command, it is showing error like

   > The config profile (profile name) could not be found